# How do I position my background image in the center of my div, but give it an offset?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I have a background image for my div that I want in the center, but offset slightly. If I do `background-position: x y;` it doesn't keep it centered as the page widens.

Comment: Pretty sure you can only offset from the top or the left. Everything else is a location, like bottom, right, center, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use percents to proportionally specify the [background-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) like so:

```
element {
    background-image: url(' ... ');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 55% 50%;
}
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7nY4r/)

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css

```
background-position{55% 0%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You either get center or offset, but not both. Even % don't work the way you expect. If the image and container are the same size, % offsets do precisely *nothing at all*. CSS background-image positioning is terrible.

What you can do, sometimes, is actually offset the image itself. Save it with extra transparent pixels on one side or the other - then center the results.